# limiting my pagination in to five and how to highlight current pagination page

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

for example i have 30 pages in my pagination and i want to limit them into five? for example when i get in the page 5. i want to see like this. `<<  5  6  7  8  9  >>`

and how to highlight my current pagination page?

here's my view how i iterate my pagination.

```
.pagination.clearfix
            | &nbsp;
            a.page ng-href="{{ ctrl.turnToPage(ctrl.current_page - 1) }}" ng-if="ctrl.search.meta.prev_page | valPresent" «
            a.page ng-href="/clients?page={{$index + 1}}" ng-show="ctrl.urlChecker2" ng-repeat=" page in getNumber(number) track by $index"
              | {{$index+1}}
            a.page ng-href="{{ctrl.turnToPage($index + 1)}}" ng-show="ctrl.urlChecker" ng-repeat=" page in getNumber(number) track by $index"
              strong
              | {{$index+1}}
            a.page href="{{ ctrl.turnToPage(ctrl.current_page + 1) }} " ng-if="ctrl.search.meta.next_page | valPresent" »
            | &nbsp;
```

thanks for fast reply cheers.

Comment: What kind of router are you using?

Comment: im using rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To highlight your current page, you can use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Like so  : `ng-class={active: <condition for active page>}`

See in the snippet below for full example.

### limitTo

To limit the pages to display, two solutions :
Use [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) to only use a slice of an array.
Like so :

```
a.page ng-href="{{ctrl.turnToPage($index + 1)}}" ng-show="ctrl.urlChecker" ng-repeat=" page in getNumber(number):limitTo:5:startIndex() track by $index"
```

`startIndex` will be a function returning the first index of the array (see below, in the snipet for a working example).

### [].constructor with use of $index

To avoid the builing of a dump pages array with index+1 in values, you can use [].constructor to build an empty array directly usable in your expression.
Then, use $index to determine the page.

Simple example (html / es6) for your use case with the *[].constructor* solution :

```js
const myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('PaginationController', () => {
  const vm = this;

  vm.pagesCount = 10
  vm.pagesToDisplay = 5;
  vm.currentPage = 1;
  
  vm.next = () => {
    return vm.currentPage = Math.min(vm.pagesCount, vm.currentPage + 1)
  }

  vm.prev = () => {
    return Math.max(1, vm.currentPage - 1)
  }

  vm.startIndex = () => {    
    if( vm.currentPage > ((vm.pagesToDisplay / 2) + 1 )) {
      if ((vm.currentPage + Math.floor(vm.pagesToDisplay / 2)) > vm.pagesCount) {
        return vm.pagesCount - vm.pagesToDisplay + 1;
      }
      return vm.currentPage - Math.floor(vm.pagesToDisplay / 2);
    }    
    return 1;
  }

  return vm;
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PaginationController as $ctrl">
    <div>currentPage : {{$ctrl.currentPage}}/{{$ctrl.pagesCount}}</div>
    <span ng-click="$ctrl.currentPage = $ctrl.prev()">prev</span>
    <span ng-click="$ctrl.currentPage = $ctrl.startIndex() + $index" ng-class="{active: ($ctrl.startIndex() + $index) == $ctrl.currentPage}" ng-repeat="_page in [].constructor($ctrl.pagesToDisplay) track by $index">{{$ctrl.startIndex() + $index}}</span>
    <span ng-click="$ctrl.currentPage = $ctrl.next()">next</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

**For your ng-href behaviour**
Turn the above code to :

```
<span ng-href="/clients?page={{$ctrl.prev()}}">prev</span>
<span ng-href="/clients?page={{$ctrl.startIndex() + $index}}" ng-class="{active: ($ctrl.startIndex() + $index) == $ctrl.currentPage}" ng-repeat="_page in [].constructor($ctrl.pagesToDisplay) track by $index">{{$ctrl.startIndex() + $index}}</span>
<span ng-href="/clients?page={{$ctrl.next()}}">next</span>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply let me try this :)

Comment: You had 6 and so pages because I didn't set max pages in my dumb example. I added to it a max page behaviour.

Comment: concerning ngHref, I can't make it work on snippet, that's why I used ngClick. I have just added a small code part to handle your ngHref example.

Comment: let me try this